# Should I .npmignore typings directory in a Typescript project

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The types I'm pulling in are for Node modules that come built in to Node. The API I'm exposing uses none of these types, so my first guess is no, I should not publish the typings directory.

In any other project I use these types, I'll need to `typings install dt~node --save --global` again right?

No chance it makes any sense to use the type definitions in project X (a dependency) which publishes typings/globals/node/index.d.ts?

Comment: Will you be shipping type definitions as part of your NPM package using the `typings:` field in `project.json`?

Comment: @IvanZlatev yes, the typings field in package.json will point to "./lib/index.d.ts" which has my type definitions (these types have nothing to do with those imported via Typings which are for node and async module).